# How do I print vector values of type glm::vec3 that have been passed by reference?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have a small obj loader and it takes two parameters and passes them back to the input variables.. however this is my first time doing this and i'm not sure how to print said values now. Here is my main function to test if the loader is working. I have two vectors of type `glm::vec3` to hold the vertex and normal data.

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;    

int main() {
    bool test = loadOBJ("cube.obj", vertices, normals);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
       std::cout << vertices[i] << std::endl;   // problem line
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

The line commented above is what is generating useless info. If I leave it like that and run the program I get a bunch of errors spewed at me (*too unformatted and long to paste here*) and if I add the reference operator I get output like this:

```
0x711ea0
0x711eac
0x711eb8
0x711ec4    // etc
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does `glm::vec3` overload `operator<<`? If not, you're probably better printing, for example, `vertices[i].x << ' ' << vertices[i].y << ' ' << vertices[i].z`

Comment: that was one of the many garbled errors i saw in the ouput window? i don't know if it does.

Comment: What output are you expecting from it? I've never heard of the class itself, but each member might be what you want. You can overload it yourself to do that, too.

Comment: similar errors when i try that @Lwin

Comment: show us the definition of glm:vec3.

Comment: Oh, and that "reference operator" is actually the address-of operator. It's used to get the address of an rvalue (the output you see is the address of each `vertices[i]` in memory), whereas a reference would be applied to a declared variable, such as in a function header. Same symbol, different meanings.

Comment: It gets the address of an lvalue. In fact, one of the simplest definitions of rvalue is that `operator&` won't apply to them.

Comment: @DeadMG, Oops, I meant lvalue :p Of course you don't go around `&5`, `&"hi"` etc.

Comment: @iKlsR The answer to your other question about printing floats is `std::copy(std::begin(verts),std::end(verts),std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));`

Comment: OK so chris found it already... for "general reference" aka let me websearch that for you... got you this close: https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00127_source.html#l00461 hope it helps.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

glm has an extension for this. Add `#include "glm/ext.hpp"` or `"glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp"`

Then to print a vector for example:

```
glm::vec4 test;
std::cout<<glm::to_string(test)<<std::endl;
```

Comment: NTS: You also need to add `GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL`, in order to use `glm::to_string`. (`glm 0.9.9.3`)

Comment: Note To Self and other c/cpp n00bs: above comment means type "`#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL`"

Comment: Also type it before including!

Comment: Seems like it no longer requires `GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL`. I just tested it with `GLM 0.9.9.9`.

Comment: Second note to self and others: `#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL` needs to come _before_ `#include "glm/ext.hpp"` (or `"glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp"`, I guess)

Answer (score 22):

I think the most elegant solution might be a combination of the two answers already posted, with the addition of templating so you don't have to reimplement the operator for all vector/matrix types (this restricts the function definition to header files, though).

```
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

template<typename genType>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const genType& g)
{
    return out << glm::to_string(g);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: what about your templating stops this function from being used with types other than the glm ones?

Comment: This only gives me "ambiguous overload".

Comment: @Ludwik Nothing other than judicious placement of the template and preexisting template specializations of `operator<<`, unfortunately, but I had little experience with SFINAE techniques at the time (still don't, for that matter) so I'll leave that exercise to someone with more experience than me. `operator<<` is generally specialized for built-in types, though, so as long as you aren't using it with classes/structs/etc. you haven't already defined a specialization for you should be okay normally. If you're getting "ambiguous overload", it means something else has a general overload for `<<`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking something, I'm getting the "ambiguous overload" for `string`.

Comment: As far as I can tell at this point, SFINAE should make it so that the provided template is only selected when a valid parameter is supplied to `glm::to_string()`, as otherwise the template should fail to compile (which should result in another template version being chosen). You may be including an overload/specialization of `operator<<` that takes a `const std::string &` as its second parameter somewhere.

Comment: SFINAE only works if one of the template parameters fails to expand. To solve ambiguous overloads, include `<type_traits>` and `<utility>`, then use `template <typename GLMType, typename = decltype(glm::to_string(std::declval<GLMType>()))>`

Answer (score 16):

`glm::vec3` doesn't overload `operator<<` so you can't print the vector itself. What you can do, though, is print the members of the vector:

```
std::cout << "{" 
          << vertices[i].x << " " << vertices[i].y << " " << vertices[i].z 
          << "}";
```

Even better, if you use that a lot, you can overload `operator<<` yourself:

```
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const glm::vec3 &vec) {
    out << "{" 
        << vec.x << " " << vec.y << " "<< vec.z 
        << "}";

    return out;
}
```

Then to print, just use:

```
std::cout << vertices[i];
```

Comment: Hey, if I have a large, multi-file project, where can I put that overload so it becomes usable everywhere?

Comment: @Ludwik, Pretty please use the extension mentioned in the other answer (this answer works more generally, but I lack knowledge of this library). If you need an overload like this for something, it works like any other class or function you'd use repeatedly. Put a declaration for it into a header and either define it in the header as `inline` to satisfy linking or define it in one implementation file.

Comment: I do use the accepted answer's extension, but it requires calling `glm::to_string` over the vector, while I'd prefer an `<<` overload. Thanks, I'll put it in a header file.

Comment: It's probably better to put it in terms of what glm provides: `operator <<(...) { return out << glm::to_string(vec); }`

Comment: @LimitedAtonement, I agree. I was unaware that this function existed until the first other answer was written. At least the answer might still be useful in certain scenarios.

Comment: @chris I've found that the functions are not discoverable at all!

Comment: never underestimate the power of URLs pointing to https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00127_source.html#l00461

Comment: The problem with the other answer is that matrices are printed in a format not really easy to understand on a glance: the columns(!) are printed in a horizontal fashion, one after another in a single line. So I think this answer still has its merit: you can print the matrix in the format _you_ need, not the one suggested by `glm::gtx::string_cast`.

Answer (score 16):

GLM has `operator<<()` in `<glm/gtx/io.hpp>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/io.hpp>

int main()
{
   glm::vec3 v(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
   std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
[    1.000,    2.000,    3.000]
```

Comment: Precision can be changed from the default of `3` using the [`glm::io::precision()` manipulator](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/1.0.1/glm/gtx/io.hpp#L122-L127): `std::cout << glm::io::precision(7) << v << std::endl;`

Comment: Similarly: [`glm::io::width()`](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/1.0.1/glm/gtx/io.hpp#L129-L134).

Answer (score 0):

To get the overload resolution right, you can do something like:

```
// Writes a generic GLM vector type to a stream.
template <int D, typename T, glm::qualifier P>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, glm::vec<D, T, P> v) {
  return os << glm::to_string(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on JAB's answer, I use the following to avoid `'operator <<' is ambiguous` errors:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

/**
 * can_cout<T> tells whether there already exists an override of operator<< that
 * supports T.
 */
template <typename, typename = void>
struct can_cout : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct can_cout<T, std::void_t<decltype(operator<<(std::declval<std::ostream>(), std::declval<T>()))> > : public std::true_type {};

/**
 * Implement operator<< iff GlmType is handled by glm::to_string but there is
 * not already an override of operator<< that hanldes this type.
 */
template<
    typename GlmType,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<!can_cout<GlmType>::value>,
    typename = decltype(glm::to_string(std::declval<GlmType>()))
>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const GlmType& g)
{
    return out << glm::to_string(g);
}
```