# How to print glm vector with manually specified precion?

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, precision, glm-math

I know about [`glm::to_string`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00295.html) but I cannot find away to set precision of the string conversion.  A few issues come up because of this.  If I want to serialize glm structures, I won't be able to store the full value in text. More recently I ran into an issue where I had a bug with a value being on the order of -10^-18, but glm insisted on showing it as -0.000 requiring me to manually print out the individual values or create my own printing function to actually see the true value (and I'd really like not to have to do that).

Does glm provide the means to set `glm::vecN` to `std::string` output precision or use [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)?

Note: the answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515469/how-do-i-print-vector-values-of-type-glmvec3-that-have-been-passed-by-referenc) do not present a way to set the precision of `glm::vecN` using `glm` built in facilities.